# Sq-lite Query does not fetch all rows from Database

Tags: wpf, sqlite

I am using Sqlite with WPF.
i face an issue that not all rows shows in the search query.
let's say i have 4 rows like below:

[image]

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data 
Source=SGenDB.sqlite;Version=3;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
m_dbConnection.Open();
SQLiteCommand commandM = new SQLiteCommand(m_dbConnection);
// sqlM

commandM.CommandText = "select * from TModels where PID=@Pid";
commandM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pid", "bb18a0d3-9dd3-4f20-a182-b90f8b79fbc2");
SQLiteDataReader readerM = commandM.ExecuteReader();
readerM.Read();
while (readerM.Read())
{
    //DataGrid Binding
    DG_LoadProject.ItemsSource = readerM;

}
```

The query return just one row always, the first row always being ignored.
I try in another data sample which has 4 rows and query returned just 3.

I create the database in the app first launching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first call to readerM.Read() line. This is reading the first row but not doing anything with it.

So the code should be:

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data 
        Source=SGenDB.sqlite;Version=3;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        SQLiteCommand commandM = new SQLiteCommand(m_dbConnection);
        // sqlM

    commandM.CommandText = "select * from TModels where PID=@Pid";
    commandM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pid", "bb18a0d3-9dd3-4f20-a182-b90f8b79fbc2");
    SQLiteDataReader readerM = commandM.ExecuteReader();
    while (readerM.Read())
    {
        //DataGrid Binding
        DG_LoadProject.ItemsSource = readerM;

    }
```